# Python redirect doesn't always work

Tags: python, redirect, safari

I made a little python script that runs as a webserver. After the user clicks on a button I want the page to redirect to the same page again. For this purpose I use the below script;

```
    self.send_response(301)
    self.send_header("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate")
    self.send_header("Pragma", "no-cache")
    self.send_header("Expires", "0")
    self.send_header('Location','192.168.2.173:80/index.shtml')
    self.end_headers()
```

The weird thing is.. this script works fine in chrome and safari on the desktop. However, when I click the button from any IOS device (tried several) I get an error in safari (on the IOS device) saying;

***Safari cannot open the page because too many redirects occured.***

I googled quite a bit.. the only solutions I have come across is emptying the cache on the IOS device.. but this doesn't help. 
Are there other ways of doing a redirect in python?

Comment: 301 is a *permanent* redirect -- I could see an eager browser get caught in a redirect loop if it ignored the caching instructions.  Or if you used a 301 redirect without caching instructions at some point, later adding caching instructions won't have any effect on cached redirects.  You might try using a 302 (or 307) header instead and see if that has any benefit.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I just tried 302 and 307.. but no difference :(